# Определить причину возникновения события actionend

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Согласно https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#event-actionend возвращает action. Что это за объект? Можно ли с его помощью определить от чего двигалась карта: программное перемещение или пользователь двинул?

Comment: вы можете просто попробовать :-)

Comment: Я пробую. alert() - мне возвращает Object. Как понять, что это за объект?

Comment: `alert` не очень хорошее средство для отладки, лучше `console.log`, `console.dir`

Comment: console.log помог! Получил такой s {events: s, _7G: null, _5H: Object, _6H: null, _7H: 0…} и такой i {events: s, _7G: null, _hV: 0, _iV: null} объекты. Не знаком с javascript, поэтому не понимаю, как это интерпретировать? Вижу, что в первом случае есть объект _5H. Как к нему обратиться?

Comment: `s._5H` или `s['_5H']` не зная правда что за `s` и `i` :-)

Comment: Запрос: myMap.events.add('actionend', function (e) {
        var action = e.get('action');
        console.log(action);
    }); при движении карты пользователем выводится: i {events: s, _7G: null, _hV: 0, _iV: null}, а при myMap.panTo() - s {events: s, _7G: null, _5H: Object, _6H: null, _7H: 0…}

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32042/discussion-between-grundy-and-blyabtroi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипты Яндекс.Карт могут быть подключены в двух режимах *release* (по-умолчанию) и *debug*. В режиме release скрипты минимизированы и приватные поля объектов (имена которых начинаются с `_`) заменяются на более короткие. При этом с каждым новым минорным релизом укороченное имя может быть разным. Поэтому я бы не стал надеяться, что в следующий раз это поле будет называться `_5H`.

В рассмотренных вами случаях `action` имеет разные типы. В случае с `Map.panTo()` это [ymaps.map.action.Single](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.action.Single-docpage/), при перемещении карты "руками" это [ymaps.map.action.Continuous](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.action.Continuous-docpage/). Поэтому их можно разделить просто по условию `(e.get('action') instanceof ymaps.map.action.Single)`. Однако есть и плохая новость. Если пользователь переместит карту двойным кликом, то `action` в событии `actionend` будет тоже типа `Single`.

Если вам нужно отделить именно окончание `panTo()`, можно задавать свойство `duration` каким нибудь нестандартным (по-умолчанию там 500, думаю что 499 будет достаточно нестандартным) и потом проверять его в обработчике события. Метод не на 100% надежный, но рабочий.

Теперь к вопросу как поверить это свойство в обработчике. Его можно получить как поле `duration` как раз того самого поля `_5H`, которое в режиме отладки называется `_originalTick`. Тут есть еще один вариант, как проверить программное перемещение, не трогая `duration` - поле `timingFunction`. При двойном клике оно равно `undefined`. Чтобы не зависеть от минимизатора, поискать его можно так:

```
function actionEndHandler(e) {
    var action = e.get('action'), moveByHand = true;
    if (action instanceof ymaps.map.action.Single) {
        for (var k in action) {
            if (action.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                // Тут можно вместо проверки !!action[k].timingFunction
                // поискать наш специфичный action[k].duration
                if (!!action[k] && !!action[k].timingFunction) {
                    moveByHand = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (moveByHand) {
        // Карта перемещена руками
    } else {
        // Карта перемещена программно
    }
}
```

PS. Если действия, которые вы хотите производить после программного перемещения не мешают действиям после ручного перемещения, то достаточно поместить их в функцию `done` промиса, который возвращается при вызове `panTo()`. Что-то вроде:

```
myMap.panTo([50, 50]).then(function () {
    // Действия после перемещения (только программного)
})
```